# jQuery input placeholder for type password in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using jQuery instead of HTML5 placeholder attribute

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="Email" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Email') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value = 'Email'; }" onclick="if (this.value == 'Email') { this.value = ''; }"  />
```

this is working fine for `type="text"` but for `type="password"` it show only *******

How i will use placeholder for password field? Need out in IE8

Advance thanks for answers...

Comment: [Placeholders.js](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) works properly with the `password` input type in all browsers except IE8 and below (and also improves upon your current solution by not submitting the placeholder value along with the form). You can't do it in IE8 and below without creating a new element temporarily.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052544/showing-placeholder-text-for-password-field-in-ie

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I create a normal input, and on `focus` switch it to a password field, and if the value is empty on `blur`, then switch it back to a normal input, else leave it as the password field.

[Here is a working JSFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/q8ajJ/) http://jsfiddle.net/q8ajJ/

**The HTML**

```
<!-- Style = display none for people who dont have javascript -->
<input type="text" name="fake_pass" id="fake_pass" value="Enter Password:" style="display:none"/>
<input type="password" name="real_pass" id="real_pass"/>​
```

**The Javascript (jQuery)**

```
// On DOM ready, hide the real password
$('#real_pass').hide();

// Show the fake pass (because JS is enabled)
$('#fake_pass').show();

// On focus of the fake password field
$('#fake_pass').focus(function(){
    $(this).hide(); //  hide the fake password input text
    $('#real_pass').show().focus(); // and show the real password input password
});

// On blur of the real pass
$('#real_pass').blur(function(){
    if($(this).val() == ""){ // if the value is empty, 
        $(this).hide(); // hide the real password field
        $('#fake_pass').show(); // show the fake password
    }
    // otherwise, a password has been entered,
    // so do nothing (leave the real password showing)
});
```

​

Answer (score 6):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zAJLF/1/) is another dirty hack - you can create `label` with `position: absolute` and show/hide it with JS on focus and blur.

As far as I know, it works in any browser. Moreover, it is more simple to validate form submitting.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <input class="withPlaceholder" type="password" id="pass" />
    <label class="placeholder" for="pass">Password</label>
</div>
<br />
<div class="wrapper">
    <input class="withPlaceholder" type="password" id="pass2" />
    <label class="placeholder" for="pass2">Password2</label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.wrapper {position: relative}
label.placeholder {position: absolute; color: #CCC; left: 2px; top: 0}
```

JS

```
$("input.withPlaceholder").on({
    focus: function() {
        $("label[for=" + $(this).prop("id") + "]").hide();
    },
    blur: function() {
        if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
            $("label[for=" + $(this).prop("id") + "]").show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This approach is just perfect for IE+ browsers especially that it doesn't interfere with any validation in place. Note that you will have to adjust your label placeholder styling so that it jives well with your current login form and that it should actually cover the length of your input type password field. :)

Answer (score 4):

Based on JustAnil's answer, and looking for a way to avoid having to manually add each corresponding  for every password fields, I came up with this adaptation of JustAnil's solution:

```
function ManagePasswords(root) {
    root.find('input[type=password][placeholder]').each(function (index, current) {
        var $current = $(current),
            $fake = $current.clone().attr('type', 'text');

        $fake.val($fake.attr('placeholder'));

        $fake.insertBefore($current);
        $current.hide();

        $fake.focusin(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).next().show().focus();
        });

        $current.blur(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).hide();
                $(this).prev().show();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Then all you have to do is call

```
ManagePasswords($('#rootElement'));
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Adding another `input` element for the placeholder may create trouble during `form` validation and submission.  I solved this in a different way.

**The HTML**

```
<form id="test">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name"  />
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
</form>
```

**jQuery Function**

```
function placeholder(form) {
    form.wrapInner('<ul style="list-style: none; list-style-type:none; padding:0; margin: 0;">');
    form.find('input[placeholder]').each(function (index, current) {
        $(current).css('padding', 0).wrap('<li style="position: relative; list-style: none; list-style-type:none; padding:0; margin: 0;">');            
        var height = $(current).parent('li').height();
        var $current = $(current),
            $placeholder = $('<div class="placeholder">'+$current.attr('placeholder')+'</div>');
        $placeholder.css({'color': '#AAA', 'position':'absolute', 'top': 0, 'left': 0, 'line-height': height+'px', 'margin': '0 0 0 5px', 'border': '0 none', 'outline': '0 none', 'padding': 0});
        $placeholder.insertAfter($current);
        $current.removeAttr('placeholder');
        $placeholder.click(function(){
            $current.focus()
        });
        $current.keypress(function(){
            if($(this).val().length >= 0) {
                $placeholder.hide();
            } 
        });
        $current.blur(function(){
            if($(this).val().length == 0) {
                $placeholder.show();
            } else {
                $placeholder.hide();
            }
        });                 
    });         
}
```

Now just call function for your form.

```
placeholder($("#test"));
```

This will work for all type of input field with placeholder including `type="password"` tested in IE8, IE9, IE10, Google Chrome, FireFox, Safari and Opera.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code, jQuery will do the rest...

html tag replace

```
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><html><![endif]-->
```

jQuery goodness...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.ie8 [placeholder][type="password"]').each(function(){
        $(this).wrap('<div style="position: relative;"></div>');
        $('<span style=" position: absolute;top: 5px;left:14px;" class="ie8Lbls">'+$(this).attr('placeholder')+'</span>').insertAfter($(this));
        $(this).attr('placeholder','');
        if($(this).val() == "") {$(this).parent().find('.ie8Lbls').show();}
    }).on('focus',function(){
        $(this).parent().find('.ie8Lbls').hide();
    }).on('blur',function(){
        if($(this).val() == "") {$(this).parent().find('.ie8Lbls').show();}
    });
    $(document).on('click','.ie8Lbls',function(){
        $(this).parent().find('input').focus();
    });

});
```

style to change the looks of the new placeholder

```
<style>
.ie8Lbls {
    font-size:10px;
}
</style>
```