# Input type password text on IE 8

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I'm working on this [website](http://codekunstler.com/test/duttipress/)

The problem I have is on the input of the password:
[image]

When you click on it on **IE9** and other browsers like Chrome and mozilla, the text changes so you can enter the password.

But that doesn't happen on IE8, if you click over it the text just stays there always, so I can't enter a pass.

This is my input code:

```
<input class="login_modal password" type="text" value="Contraseña" onfocus="this.type='password';this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.type='text';this.value='Contraseña';}" />
```

Any ideas to make it work cross-browser and Ie8 also?

Comment: Not abusing `value` as a replacement for `<label>` in the first place would be a good start.

Comment: Use `placeholder` and degrade gracefully.

Comment: I think `placeholder` won't work with ie8...

Comment: check this previously answered question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415151/jquery-input-placeholder-for-type-password-in-ie8

Comment: I think you should use jquery more, defining events not in input markup but in javascript block

Comment: Older IE don’t allow changing the `type` of input fields (as this property was defined as readonly in an early DOM specification). You can only create a new field, and replace the existing one with that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery like :

```
var defaultVal = 'Contraseña';


$('.password').on('focus', function(){
     var $this = $(this);
     var valOfThisBox = $this.val();

     if(valOfThisBox === '' ){
        this.val(defaultVal);
     }else{
        this.attr('type','password').val('');
     }
});
```

Comment: I changed it to this, but it just keeps the text and doesn't change to type password on focus... you can see it on the link

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'val' `

Comment: try using older versions of jquery, like 1.7 or 1.8, I don't have IE 8, running in Chrome is not making any issue....

Comment: I'm testing it right now in chrome, if you load the page the pass is blank and if I click and type, it just shows the password, so no `type="password"` there

Comment: You removed the code...right?

Comment: changed the input to: `<input class="login_modal password" type="text" value="" />`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css selector focus:

```
loginModal password:focus, loginModalPassword.focus { loginmodalpassword.type='password' }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function using jQuery some time ago

usage: `_describeInput($("#idOfYourInputField"));`

alternative: `_describeInput($("input[name=NameOfYourInputField]"));`

You may want to change the colors being applied, this one was a quick draft for dark backgrounded websites. Works pretty well for me tho.

```
function _describeInput(_field=false)
{
if (!$(_field)) { return false; }

$(_field).unbind();

$(_field).focus(function(){
    $(this).val(($(this).val()==$(this).attr("description"))?"":$(this).val());
    $(this).css({"color":"white"});
});

$(_field).focusout(function(){
    $(this).css({"color":(($(this).val()==$(this).attr("description"))?"gray":"white")});           
    $(this).val(($(this).val()=="")?$(this).attr("description"):$(this).val());
});

$(_field).css({"color":"gray"}).attr("description",$(_field).val());
}
```