# Input placeholder script that works on IE 8 password fields without JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, placeholder

Yet another placeholder in IE question...

I am currently using this Placeholders.js script: https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js

Unfortunately, like all other "update the value of the input field" placeholder polyfills, it fails on password fields since the value of a password field is shown as stars.  I need it to work on a password field so this is a deal-breaker.

This is for a JSP app, not a Javascript app, and the use of Javascript is minimal.  I would prefer not have a JQuery dependency if I can possibly help it.  Yet nearly all of the placeholder polyfills I can find are JQuery plugins.

Has anyone found a script that handles this case without JQuery?  I would prefer to not write my own since there are so many edge cases.

Comment: I know you said without jQuery, but here is a good one that uses jQuery and also works for password/IE: https://github.com/danielstocks/jQuery-Placeholder/blob/master/jquery.placeholder.js

Comment: Yeah, I definitely have a wealth of options if I go with JQuery, so that is plan B.  This question is just one last try to find a non-JQuery solution.

Comment: Ugh, just the thought of testing a non-jQuery solution in all legacy browsers makes me want to go home...

Comment: I have now tried about 6 different JQuery ones, and this is the only one that didn't have some bugs in my use case: https://github.com/dciccale/placeholder-enhanced . Given that, I'll probably just use JQuery, since even if I find a non-JQuery one, I don't have high hopes for it being bug-free

Comment: As a long-past follow-up, we did end up using that one I linked above.  The sticking points for other ones tended to be IE7 support and lack of support for password fields.  A surprising number of the polyfills show the placeholder as ********* in password fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can find many examples on SO, here is one example which seems to work for many.  And for all input types:

[Showing Placeholder text for password field in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052544/showing-placeholder-text-for-password-field-in-ie)

Comment: Aren't those all JQuery solutions?

Comment: Well yes, but you can of course rewrite most of it to simple java script without the use of a library. But this is reinventing the wheel. You should read the rest of the link I gave though. See for example DavidJCobb answer in that thread using almost no JS at all.

Comment: Like you said, it's reinventing the wheel. I can do it but I would like to see if the wheel I need exists already.

Comment: True, but in the time looking for an existing snippet which might not exist, for a browser which will be soon have discontinued support on a lot of platforms. You could have made a snippet your own. You could even copy a lot of javascript JQuery uses for the solution if you download the not minified source. Just saying: searching for snippets / code isn't always the most profitable / workable solution. In your case: passwordfield placeholder -> no jquery / ie8 / and minimal javascript. Especially the minimal javascript demand, should conclude in best to write your own snippet.