# Setup place-holder for the text-box input[type=" password"]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show placeholder text(enter password) for the text-box which has input[type="password"]. Now i am trying to  change the *input[type="password"]* to  *input[type="text"]* to show the placeholder and if the user click the text box i am again changing the *input[type="text"]* to *input[type="password"]*. Here it is not working please check script 
 
My **[jsfiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/9HagB/3/)**

```
 function setupPasswordPlaceholder(thisEl)
    {
        if('' !== thisEl.attr("alt"))
        {
            if('' === thisEl.val())
            {
                thisEl.val(thisEl.attr("alt"));
                thisEl.removeAttr("type");
                thisEl.attr('type','text');
                thisEl.css({'font-weight':'normal','font-size':'10pt','color':'#999','font-family': '"lucida grande", tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif'});
            }
            thisEl.focus(function()
            {        
                if(thisEl.val() == thisEl.attr("alt")) 
                {
                    thisEl.val("");
                    thisEl.removeAttr("type");
                    thisEl.attr('type','password');
                    thisEl.css({'color': '#18A505','font-size': '10pt','font-weight':'normal'});
                }

        });

        thisEl.focusout(function()
        {        
            if('' === thisEl.val()) 
            {
                thisEl.val(thisEl.attr("alt"));
                thisEl.removeAttr("type");
                thisEl.attr('type','text');
                thisEl.css({'font-weight':'normal','font-size':'10pt','color':'#999','font-family': '"lucida grande", tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif'});
            }
        });
    }
}



$("input[type='password']").each(function(){
        setupPasswordPlaceholder($(this));
});
```

​

Comment: HTML5 added a placeholder attribute to input boxes.  Is this not an adequate solution for you?  `<input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" />`

Comment: sorry i am using html4, in this here is no option for that, and ie6, ie7 won't support html5

Comment: The DOM isn't very friendly when trying to change the type attribute of an input element.  The last time I played around with this it was only successful when detaching the element from the DOM, changing the attribute, and then reattaching it.  It's a hack at best.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f5fYc/

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/9HagB/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/9HagB/6/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Showing Placeholder text for password field in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052544/showing-placeholder-text-for-password-field-in-ie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple code change for you might work in most browsers (other than IE6 ofcourse). You are using removeAttr and then setting the attr for property 'type', instead use this single line:

replace:

```
  thisEl.removeAttr("type");
  thisEl.attr('type','text');
```

with:

```
  thisEl.get(0).type = type;
```

See your updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9HagB/7/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5fYc)**

HTML:

```
    <input style="display: none; " id="fakepasscode" type="password" autocomplete="off">
    <input style="display: inline;" id="passcode" hint="password" type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

JavaScript:

```
var clearField = function() {
    if ($("#passcode").val() != "password") {
        $("#passcode").val("");
    }
}

var resetField = function() {
    if ($("#passcode").val().length == 0) $("#passcode").val("password");
}


var pwdFocus = function() {
    $("#passcode").hide();
    $("#fakepasscode").val("");
    $("#fakepasscode").show();
    $("#fakepasscode").focus();
}

var pwdBlur = function() {
    if ($("#fakepasscode").val() == "") {
        $("#fakepasscode").hide();
        $("#passcode").show();
    }
}

var setupHintField = function() {
    $("#passcode").unbind("focus blur change");
    $("#passcode").focus(function() {
        clearField();
    });
    $("#passcode").blur(function() {
        resetField();
    });
    $("#passcode").change(function() {
        resetField();
    });
    $("#passcode").show();
    $("#fakepasscode").hide();
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#passcode").val($("#passcode").attr("hint"));
    setupHintField();
    $("#passcode").unbind("focus");
    $("#passcode").focus(function() {
        pwdFocus();
    });
    $("#fakepasscode").blur(function() {
        pwdBlur();
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

The common solution to this I have seen is to use a label or another input box to show the "placeholder" text in IE.

Please see this excellent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7225820/988355