# How to put a text watermark in a password field?

Tags: jquery, html

I want a watermark in my password field which says "Password".
Here is my code:
jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var watermark = 'Password';

    //init, set watermark text and class
    $('#input_pwd').val(watermark).addClass('watermark');

    //if blur and no value inside, set watermark text and class again.
    $('#input_pwd').blur(function(){
        if ($(this).val().length == 0){
            $(this).val(watermark).addClass('watermark');
        }
    });

    //if focus and text is watermrk, set it to empty and remove the watermark class
    $('#input_pwd').focus(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == watermark){
            $(this).val('').removeClass('watermark');
        }
    });
});
```

html:

```
<input class="ui_input" id="input_pwd" type="password" name="pass" id="pass" style="height:25px; width:250px; font-size:14px;" required />
```

My jsfiddle:
 [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/w4Hh4/)

edit: I prefer jquery :)

edit: Our brother Konrad Gadzina has given me what I was looking for but thanks for all your efforts everyone!

Comment: do you mean "placeholder" ?

Comment: https://github.com/Topener/jQuery-html5-placeholder

Comment: Before you go further, learn the definition of both watermark and placeholder - they're not even nearly related.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Showing Placeholder text for password field in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052544/showing-placeholder-text-for-password-field-in-ie)

Answer (score 8):

You can set the `type` to be `text` by default and change it to `password` with JS while removing `watermark` class.

HTML:

```
<input class="ui_input" id="input_pwd" type="text" name="pass" id="pass" style="height:25px; width:250px; font-size:14px;" required />
```

JS:

```
    //if blur and no value inside, set watermark text and class again.
    $('#input_pwd').blur(function(){
        if ($(this).val().length == 0){
            $(this).val(watermark).addClass('watermark');
            $(this).attr('type', 'text');
        }
    });

    //if focus and text is watermrk, set it to empty and remove the watermark class
    $('#input_pwd').focus(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == watermark){
            $(this).val('').removeClass('watermark');
            $(this).attr('type', 'password');
        }
    });
```

Check fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/w4Hh4/1/

Comment: @Tom grat, I'm glad it helped. If this answer fits your needs, remember to mark it as accepted answer to show that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 5):

Use html's `placeholder`

```
<input class="ui_input" id="input_pwd" type="password" name="pass" id="pass" style="height:25px; width:250px; font-size:14px;" placeholder='Password' required />
```

And you don't need any js for it.

NOTE: The placeholder attribute is supported in Internet Explorer 10, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari. Unfortunatly as stated in the comments it won't work for older IE

Comment: For IE < 9 you will need JS still

Comment: Is it supported by mozilla firefox?

Comment: @Tom It is supported in Firefox yes

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `placeholder` input property.

```
Username:<input type='text' placeholder="Username"/> <br/>
Password: <input type='text' placeholder="Password"/>
```

Please see this [jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/KevinIsNowOnline/cX8Zt/)

Comment: We can see that there'a bunch of downvotes within this SO question, can you explain why? User explicitly didn't specify the browser that he uses, we just based our assumption on the jquery() snippet on his code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support Internet Explorer, you can do it with floated labels on top of the input field. I.e., the `<input>` tag has a corresponding `<label>` tag that has a `float: left` in CSS and the they are positioned so that the label is on top of the input field. You'd also need to add `.click()` event handler to the label that activates the input field and hides the label, and `.focus()` and `.blur()` on the input field that respectively hide and show the label.

If you don't need to support Internet Explorer, the `placeholder` attribute for `<input>` tags should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simple do

Adding `placeholder="your initial value"` will solve the issue I hope.

Comment: this is HTML5 attribute. Old browsers such as Firefox 3.x won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use HTML5, then try switching modes as suggested per the first answer by @Konrad Gadzina or try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w4Hh4/3/

Put a textbox next to the password box and switch it on focus and blur.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var watermark = 'Password';

   //init, set watermark text and class
      $('#input_pwd').hide();
      $('#input_pwd_fake').val(watermark).addClass('watermark');

//if blur and no value inside, set watermark text and class again.
$('#input_pwd').blur(function(){

    if ($(this).val() == ''){
        $(this).hide();
        $('#input_pwd_fake').show().val(watermark).addClass('watermark');
    }
});

//if focus and text is watermrk, set it to empty and remove the watermark class
$('#input_pwd_fake').focus(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $('#input_pwd').show().focus();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work cross browser as it's a simple JavaScript to check if a value is set and equals the default set value either onfocus or onblur

```
<input type="password" onfocus="if(this.value=='Password') {this.value='';}" onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.value='Password'}" value="Password" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one mentioned the [jQuery Placeholder plugin](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) by Mathrias. It allows the use of the placeholder attribute for older browsers that do not support HTML5, like IE8.

Demo: http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/placeholder

Be careful with font though, IE8 doesn't support the dots in password fields for custom fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Set a class for the watermark in CSS

```
input.watermark {
    color: #D3D3D3; font-weight: 400;
}
```

jQuery:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var watermark = ''; // watermark value

    $('#myID').val(watermark).addClass('watermark');

    $('#myID').blur(function(){
        if ($(this).val().length == 0){
            $(this).val(watermark).addClass('watermark');
        }
    });

    $('#input_fname').focus(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == watermark){
            $(this).val('').removeClass('watermark');
        }
    });
});
```