# HTML Password Input With Prompt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, passwords, masking

I wish to have an input field with the prompt inside the field to save presentation space.

Is it possible to have a cross browser password input field on a form that has a text prompt such as Password: * as you start typing it either masks the password or is a true password field.

If you post the form, capture the response which is immediately stored as a password, therefore not text and as a value is submitted no prompt, but should you clear the box, the prompt Password: * re appears.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Showing Placeholder text for password field in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052544/showing-placeholder-text-for-password-field-in-ie)

Comment: In this [SO-Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052544/showing-placeholder-text-for-password-field-in-ie) there are many answers and one jsfiddle example that might help [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mNchn/) from the Answer of Kei.

Comment: Just use `<input type="password" placeholder="Password: *">` (together with a polyfill for IE if you need it)

Comment: Problem Solved :You can do the trick follow this URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028615/browser-rember-me-password-prompt-disable/34615586#34615586

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking to watermark the input field. If you are using jQuery, you can use the [watermark plugin](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/). This particular plugin works for password marked inputs.

Or you can also use HTML 5's Placeholder as seen [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233699/how-to-put-a-text-watermark-in-a-password-field).

Comment: Thank you, that led me to http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/placeholder which seems to work across all browser I have tried :-)

Answer (score 3):

`HTML5` has the `placeholder` attribute, which you can apply to an `input` element, like this:

```
<input type="password" placeholder="Enter your password here..." />
```

If you need to support `placeholder-like` capability in pre-HTML5 browsers, then check out [Cross-Browser Support For HTML5 Placeholder Text In Forms](http://www.cssnewbie.com/cross-browser-support-for-html5-placeholder-text-in-forms/#.UdsPofnVAwE)

Comment: Thank you but the answer needs to be a true cross browser solution, not just HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="password" placeholder="password goes here" />`

http://jsfiddle.net/qwGd6/

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Note that this is not supported in IE9 and below.  Go figure.