# Browser Rember me Password prompt disable

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to disable the remember me password prompt of IE/firefox/chrome browser
may developer and blog suggest me to add `autocomplete ="off"` in `<form>` tag
but it's not working.

Please  give suitable answer thank in advance..

Comment: Are you using the latest versions of browser?

Answer (score 0):

//You can change the type of the password field to text before submitting the form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
    return true;

}

function copyPass() {
    document.getElementById("hidPassword").value = document.getElementById("passwordField").value;
 if (document.getElementById("passwordField").value != "") {
        var passwordLength = document.getElementById("passwordField").value.length;
       document.getElementById("passwordField").value =  "•".repeat(passwordLength);
    }
    document.getElementById("passwordField").type = 'text';
}

function changeType() {
    document.getElementById("passwordField").type = 'password';
 document.getElementById("passwordField").value = document.getElementById("hidPassword").value;
}
</script>
<form method="post" action="yoururl" runat="server">

      <input type="text" name="username" />
      <input type="password" id="passwordField" name="passwordField" onfocus="javascript:changeType()" onblur="javascript: copyPass()" />
          <input type="hidden" name="hidPassword" id="hidPassword" value="" />
      <input type="submit" runat="server" name="btnsubmit" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:return validate()" />

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `autocomplete="off"` on a `<form>` tag, set it on the individual `<input>` tags.

For browser support, see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-autocomplete-onoff).